# How to store PathGeometry in (SQL) database?

Tags: sql-server, serialization, pathgeometry

I've got .net classes containing PathGeometries and need to store these in a SQL Server database.

What columntype would I use and how do I get the PathGeometry into the column and back?

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I know very little about PathGeometry, but SQL Server 2008 has a GEOMETRY spatial type that may be of use to you. Here is a link to some details on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx). That should be able to get you to a point where you can save the data to the database. However, my lack of knowledge about the Geometry class prevents me from being able to help you retrieve the data from the database into a Geometry object.

Hope that helps out a little.